fl_chart flutter package repeated x value not ascending or descending value causing line chart problem
if my list of  FlSpots x value is not ascending or descending or has repeated value
(in this case number 2) causing the line to go back to the x value 2 and then continuing.
i want my line chart to move left to right no matter what. it will show another 2 value on bottom.
This is how it looks like
Here is my code:
List chartData = [
FlSpot(0, 1),
FlSpot(1, 3),
FlSpot(2, 10),
FlSpot(3, 7),
FlSpot(4, 12),
FlSpot(5, 13),
FlSpot(6, 17),
FlSpot(7, 15),
FlSpot(9, 20),
FlSpot(10, 11),
FlSpot(11, 3),
FlSpot(2, 14),
FlSpot(23, 7),
FlSpot(14, 12),
FlSpot(15, 13),
FlSpot(16, 17),
FlSpot(17, 15),
FlSpot(18, 20),
];
          SizedBox(
            height: 400.h,
            width: double.maxFinite,
            child: LineChart(
              LineChartData(
                  titlesData: const FlTitlesData(
                    bottomTitles: AxisTitles(
                        sideTitles: SideTitles(
                      showTitles: true,
                      reservedSize: 38,
                      
                    )),
                    leftTitles: AxisTitles(
                        sideTitles: SideTitles(
                      showTitles: false,
                    )),
                    topTitles: AxisTitles(
                        sideTitles: SideTitles(
                      showTitles: false,
                    )),


                    
                  ),
                  // borderData: FlBorderData(show: true),
                  lineBarsData: [
                    LineChartBarData(spots: chartData, isStrokeJoinRound : true,),
                  ]
                  ),
            ),
          ),

i want my line chart to move left to right no matter what. it will show another 2 value on bottom.
